# Sum of certain HashMap values in list only if there is a match in value under a different key

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream

I have an ArrayList filled with thousands of HashMaps having four keys and values mapped to them built like so:

```
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("ID", 1);
map.put("NAME", name);
map.put("WORK_TIME", workTime);
map.put("ACCOUNT", name);
```

now having an ArrayList of those HashMaps I would like to sum work times of people having same id, name, and account for example:

```
HashMap<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("ID", 1);
map1.put("NAME", "Edward");
map1.put("WORK_TIME", 20);
map1.put("ACCOUNT", null);

HashMap<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<>();
map2.put("ID", 1);
map2.put("NAME", "Krzych");
map2.put("WORK_TIME", 6);
map2.put("ACCOUNT", 123);

HashMap<String, Object> map3 = new HashMap<>();
map3.put("ID", 1);
map3.put("NAME", "Edward");
map3.put("WORK_TIME", 13.5);
map3.put("ACCOUNT", null);

HashMap<String, Object> map4 = new HashMap<>();
map4.put("ID", 2);
map4.put("NAME", "Grzesiek");
map4.put("WORK_TIME", 50);
map4.put("ACCOUNT", null);

HashMap<String, Object> map5 = new HashMap<>();
map5.put("ID", 2);
map5.put("NAME", "Edward");
map5.put("WORK_TIME", 12);
map5.put("ACCOUNT", 123);

[..]

ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> arrList = new ArrayList<>();
arrList.put..
```

as result I should get an ArrayList of 4 HashMaps, where only two Edward HashMaps of same id and account got merged into single one having work time of 33.5.

The only thing I came up with was iterating over all maps, comparing those three values and then succesfully replacing work time values in hashmaps stored in second arraylist
I'm working in Java 8 and I would like to accomplish this using streams, is that possible? Or do you see better solution?

Comment: Use concrete classes to perform such operations. e.g. `class Employee { int id; String name;int workTime;Integer account;}` . Further, you can collect these `toMap` with `name` as a key and merging the values accordingly.

Comment: I agree with all given answers, however, where do the data come from? My guess is that data come from some kind of database, and therefore it would be wise to perform GROUP BY directly at database level.

Comment: Yes, you are right, all the data comes from database. Thank's for suggestion, I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this lambda:

```
Map<String, List<HashMap<String, Object>>> xxx = arrList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> ((int) x.get("ID") + "") + x.get("NAME")));
```

is giving result like below:

[image]

but, like mentioned above - you should use (if possible) objects instead of Arrays.
With objects lambda would look like this:

```
Map<String, List<Person>> xxx = arrList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x.getName() + x. getId()));
```

but since you have Person class, you could overwrite equals to match your needs, and you could map and sum worktime in one simple lambda:

```
Map<Person, Double> result = arrList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x, Collectors.summingDouble(Person::getWorkTime)));
```

and this is result - a map of Person as a key, and worktime summary as a value.
[image]

code for Person class:

```
public class Person {
        String name;
        int id;
        double workTime;

        public Person(String name, int id, double workTime) {
            this.name = name;
            this.id = id;
            this.workTime = workTime;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            Person person = (Person) o;
            return id == person.id &&
                    Objects.equals(name, person.name);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {

            return Objects.hash(name, id);
        }
    }
```

example code:

```
Person person1 = new Person("Edward", 1, 20);
Person person2 = new Person("Krzych", 1, 6);
Person person3 = new Person("Edward", 1, 13.5);
Person person4 = new Person("Grzesiek", 2, 50);
Person person5 = new Person("Edward", 2, 12);

ArrayList<Person> arrList = new ArrayList<>();

arrList.add(person1);
arrList.add(person2);
arrList.add(person3);
arrList.add(person4);
arrList.add(person5);

Map<Person, Double> result = arrList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x, Collectors.summingDouble(Person::getWorkTime)));
```